# Can Someone help me in removing two single quotes for a string inside list in Python

Tags: python, list

```
list1 = [''ABC'',''XYZ'',''PQR'',''MNS'']
```

to

```
list1 = ['ABC','XYZ','PQR','MNS']
```

#I am using this code but it is not working

```
for i in range(0,len(list1)):
    list1[i] = list1[i].replace("''","")
```

Comment: Is the first snippet a string? As code it is invalid syntax.

Comment: change " ' ' " to " ' " in replace function and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find list comprehension to be the cleanest solution:

```
list2 = [s.replace("'", "") for s in list1]
```

In the snippet above, I iterate through the list binding `s` to each of the characters (as we traverse the list). In each iteration, I do the replacement.

Comment: Did you try that with `list1 = [''ABC'',''XYZ'',''PQR'',''MNS'']`?

Comment: Yes, I tested with the original list and it gets properly modified as the author of this post requested. list1 stays unmodified and list2 contains the trimmed contents

Comment: Do you run a special version of Python? In all versions known to me `[''ABC'',''XYZ'',''PQR'',''MNS'']` will give you a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: That's because you can't have single quotes in a string defined by single quotes, and the same with double quotes. You either have to do `["'ABC'","'XYZ'","'PQR'","'MNS'"]` or `['"ABC"','"XYZ"','"PQR"','"MNS"']`

If you really need double quotes in a string defined by double quotes, or vise versa, you have to add a backslash to escape the character: `['\'ABC\'','\'XYZ\'','\'PQR\'','\'MNS\'']`